# Getline error in c++

Tags: c++, getline

I am trying to read the first line of a file into a string in c++ using getline().  The problem I am having is it reads the whole file into that string, not the first line only.

How can I get it to read the first line only?

Here is my code:

```
while (!fin.eof())
{
    getline(fin, title);
    cout << title << endl;
    /*getline(fin, director);
    cout << director << endl;
    getline(fin, year);
    cout << year<<endl;
    getline(fin, rating);
    cout << rating <<endl;
    getline(fin, url);
    getline(fin, actor);
    /*
    while (actor.compare("$$$$")!=1)
    {
        actors.push_back(actor);
        getline(fin, actor);
    }
    */

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The getline is in a while loop, so the loop repeats until you hit the end of the file, getting a new line each time

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether you are speacking about the first iteration of the loop or about the result of the loop.

In the first case it means that there is no lines in the file that is that the file doesn contain  new line characters. You can use member function getline specifying the number of characters you are going to read. For example

```
const size_t N = 100;

char buffer[N];

fin.getline( buffer, N );
```

Or you should add the new line character for each group of data written in the file that then to read the file line by line.

Check the code that forms the file. Maybe you forgot to write new line characters.